# notifications from the proximity sensor (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to create an app that can detect ambient light through the proximity sensor of dervice, when the brightness of the background is 45% the 'app must send a notification .Someone have an idea how I can do to create this app thanks to the 'interest you would do me a great favor if I inviaste code ready since I'm a beginner (I'm studying it). Thank for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

The idea will work like this.

you have to create a observer notification on brightness level and the value you can get through the code below

```
NSLog(@"brightness %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);
```

So once you  get the value create a notification observer and call that in your views or any where you want to have an alert or local notification.
 You can find this link for creating local notification http://www.devfright.com/uilocalnotification-tutorial/

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply but where do I put the line of code that you gave me, I followed the tutorial you gave me but I did not understand thanks FBengine